# Azure functions ActivityTrigger and HttpTrigger lock

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, azure-functions

Can I safely use lock{} inside Azure AcitityTrigger and HttpTrigger functions or I have to work it around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't see why it shouldn't work, note that this would work only in the context of a single instance and won't hold when your app scales out.

Across function app instances, you will have to go for a distributed lock like using [storage blob leases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob).

Also, it's better to leverage a queue (like [Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview)) with appropriate concurrency config to ensure not hitting [timeouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout).